# Quarto: Howto use a custom (Web)font?

Tags: html, css, quarto

I'm trying to get a [Quarto](https://quarto.org) home page of the ground and one requirement is a custom font (free webfont; [Tex-Gyre-Adventor](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/tex-gyre-adventor)).

Following the documentation, I have played around with the `html` format specific `mainfont` tag in various iterations (see header example below), but cannot make this work - including if the font is additionally defined as a `@font-face` in `style.css` (and many other attempts).

Can anyone point me in the right direction how to use `mainfont` with a non-standard font?

Thanks for any pointers!

```
---
title: "Page"
title-block-banner: false
format:
  html:
    theme: vapor
    mainfont: `https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/tex-gyre-adventor`
    code-fold: true
    toc: false
    number-sections: false
link-citations: yes
---
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a custom webfont as the `mainfont`, just add font stylesheet file in document header using `header-includes` and set the font name in `mainfont` yaml key.

````
---
title: "Page"
title-block-banner: false
format:
  html:
    theme: vapor
    code-fold: true
    toc: false
    number-sections: false
    header-includes: |
      <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org//face/tex-gyre-adventor" type="text/css"/>
link-citations: yes
mainfont: TeXGyreAdventorRegular
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a
finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

## Running Code

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that
includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed 
code like this:

```{r}
1 + 1
```
````

---

[image: HTML page with custom webfont]

---

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! Is the process very different if one would like to use self-hosted fonts? (I'm thinking of the [IBM Plex](https://github.com/IBM/plex) family.) In that case I'll ask a separate question. Cheers!

Comment: @pglpm, yes AFAIK the CSS part should be different. Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75464776/10858321) may be of help in that regard.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've actually just discovered that the IBM Plex family is also available on Google fonts, so I can use your answer above! Thank you × 2