# How to override the default font using locally stored fonts in themes?

Tags: css, quarto, google-fonts

I am using Quarto to build a website and try to override the default fonts within a theme. (My overall goal is to use local google fonts instead of using the google api).

my `_quarto.yml` looks like that:

```
project:
  type: website

format:
  html:
    theme: 
      light: [flatly, light.scss]
```

the `light.scss` does look like that. All fonts are in `fonts/`

```
/*-- scss:defaults --*/

/* lato-regular - latin-ext_latin */
@font-face {
  font-display: swap; 
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('fonts/lato-v23-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Chrome 36+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
       url('fonts/lato-v23-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff') format('woff'); /* Chrome 5+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}
```

I am using the developer mode in chromium to investigate, if the local files are used. Unfortunately, my custom.scss i.e.,(`light.scss`) is not able to override the default configuation.

How is it possible to override the use of the api and use local fonts instead?

Comment: by `custom.scss`, do you mean `light.scss`?

Comment: yes. I edited my comment accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### updated answer based on [this discussion](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/4387#issuecomment-1433603210)

- At first, explicitly disable the path to webfonts that `flatly` theme is using by overriding the Sass variable `$web-font-path` (by giving a bad value to it like `$web-font-path: "No"`).
- Secondly, though You have defined a `@font-face`, you have not used that. You need to tell quarto to use that font and you can do it by defining [Sass variables](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-themes.html#fonts) `$font-family-sans-serif` (use it to define the sans-serif font family for the page) or `$font-family-monospace` (use it to define monospace font family for the page) in the `light.scss` file.
- Finally, an important thing to note that, Sass variable declaration need to go under the `/*-- scss:defaults --*/` layer and `@font-face` declaration need to go under the `/*-- scss:rules --*/` layer.

Therefore the **`light.scss`** file should look like,

```
/*-- scss:defaults --*/

$font-family-sans-serif: "Lato";
$font-family-monospace: "Lato";
$bs-body-font-family: "Lato";
$web-font-path: "No";

/*-- scss:rules --*/

/* lato-regular - latin-ext_latin */
@font-face {
  font-display: swap;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("./fonts/lato-v23-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("./fonts/lato-v23-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff") format("woff");
}

/* lato-italic - latin-ext_latin */
@font-face {
  font-display: swap;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("./fonts/lato-v23-latin-ext_latin-italic.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("./fonts/lato-v23-latin-ext_latin-italic.woff") format("woff");
}

/* lato-700 - latin-ext_latin */
@font-face {
  font-display: swap;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url("./fonts/lato-v23-latin-ext_latin-700.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("./fonts/lato-v23-latin-ext_latin-700.woff") format("woff");
}

/* lato-700italic - latin-ext_latin */
@font-face {
  font-display: swap;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url("./fonts/lato-v23-latin-ext_latin-700italic.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("./fonts/lato-v23-latin-ext_latin-700italic.woff") format("woff");
}
```

Comment: Better than `$web-font-path: "No";` is `$web-font-path: "";` because an empty (but non-null) value makes the Bootswatch code embedded into the theme file (see the response by @cedri-rossi) skip file loading instead of attempting to load a bogus file "No".

See [Sass documentaiton on default values](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables/#default-values)

Answer (score 1):

The [scss code](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/blob/v5/dist/flatly/_bootswatch.scss) for the Flatly theme starts with:

```
$web-font-path: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap" !default;
@if $web-font-path {
  @import url($web-font-path);
}
```

Iterating on @shafee's answer, by putting the following in light.scss

```
/*-- scss:defaults --*/

@font-face {
  font-display: swap; 
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Chrome 36+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
       url('fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2') format('woff'); /* Chrome 5+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}


$font-family-sans-serif: 'Lato'; 

$web-font-path: "fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2";
```

everything gets loaded locally.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. It seems like I am still overseeing something. As you can see in the screenshot, the issue still remains with the normal style as well. I also added `$font-size-root: 'Lato';`whitout success.

Comment: I think it's theme specific; I'm changing my answer to make it work for flatly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `embed-resource: TRUE` in the header of `index.qmd`:

This will include everything, javascript, css etc. in a stand-alone version, and there will be no CSS linking to Google fonts.

```
---
title: "GoogleFontIssue"
embed-resources: true
---
```